# About tf.data.Dataset, tf.shape() with ? in height and width, but i want use h and w to random crop from image, how can i do it

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I want to randomly crop a pic between hr and lr in the same middle area with different size, but I can't get the fixed h, w.

How can I do this with tf.data.Datasets (tensorflow)?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def random_crop(self, lr, hr, size, scale=1):
    h, w = lr.shape[:-1]
    if h < size or w < size:
        raise RuntimeError('the height or width of pic is smaller than size')

    x = random.randint(0, h//scale-size)
    y = random.randint(0, w//scale-size)
    hx, hy = x*scale, y*scale

    lr = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(lr, y, x, size, size)
    hr = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(hr, hy, hx, size*scale, size*scale)

    return lr, hr
```

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1vTz.png)

Comment: Please provide some code for people to work with. The question is a little vague and difficult to make sense of.

Comment: I provide some pic in the questions, but it seems can't worker